# "TABLE_NOT_AVAILABLE" .net SAP Connector in Powershell

Tags: powershell, sap-dotnet-connector

I´m writing a Powerhsell script that opens a order bill. First of all I set the connection - this works, because I tested it with the SAP GUI. I have the same script written in VBS, and I want to translate it. I get this error:

```
Ausnahme beim Aufrufen von "Invoke" mit 1 Argument(en):  "TABLE_NOT_AVAILABLE"
In C:\Users\x\Desktop\script.ps1:70 Zeichen:9
+         $rfcFunction.Invoke($destination)
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RfcAbapException
```

But i know it has to be this directory. what is wrong with my script until that point.

My script in Powershell until yet:

```
    #load .net sap connector
    Function Load-NCo {

      $CurrentDir = Get-Location
      [System.IO.Directory]::SetCurrentDirectory($CurrentDir.Path)

      $rc = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Program Files\SAP\SAP_DotNetConnector3_Net40_x64\" + "sapnco.dll")
      $rc = [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Program Files\SAP\SAP_DotNetConnector3_Net40_x64\" + "sapnco_utils.dll")
    }
    Function Get-Destination2 ([String]$TableName) {

      #-Verbindungsparamter---------------------------------------------
        $cfgParams = New-Object SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcConfigParameters

        $cfgParams.Add("NAME", "SAPconnect")
        $cfgParams.Add("ASHOST", "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx")
        $cfgParams.Add("SYSNR", "xx")
        $cfgParams.Add("CLIENT", "xxx")
        $cfgParams.Add("USER", "testuser")

        $cfgParams.Add("SYSID ","Txx")
        $cfgParams.Add("LANG","DE")
        $cfgParams.Add("PASSWD", "TestX")



         $destination = [SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcDestinationManager]::GetDestination($cfgParams) 

      #-Metadata--------------------------------------------------------
        $rfcFunction = `
          $destination.Repository.CreateFunction("RFC_READ_TABLE")

      #-Call function module--------------------------------------------
       
          $rfcFunction.SetValue("query_table", $TableName)
          $rfcFunction.SetValue("DELIMITER", ";")


        $rfcFunction.Invoke($destination)
      

        Write-Host [SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcDestinationManager]::GetDestination($cfgParams)


    }


    Load-NCo

    Get-Destination2("Z_GET_ARCHIVE_FILE_URL")
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this [Guide to Using RFC_READ_TABLE to Query SAP Tables](https://success.jitterbit.com/display/DOC/Guide+to+Using+RFC_READ_TABLE+to+Query+SAP+Tables). This error is due to an incorrect table name being passed here:

```
$rfcFunction.SetValue("query_table", $TableName)
```

For troubleshooting, try writing `$rfcFunction` and `$destination` to the console:

```
$rfcFunction
$destination
$rfcFunction.Invoke($destination)
```